# Detached v/s transient entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm really confused between detached and transient entity. According to the definition, a transient entity is not associated with a session and does not have a DB record. A detached entity is associated with a session and has a DB record. So for ex. if I have a Person table. There is a record in the person table with id as 2. So if I do the following:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setId(2);
```

Will the entity p be considered detached since it has a DB record but is not associated with a session? Or will it be considered transient? If it is transient then is the following code a correct example of creating a detached entity?

```
Person p = session.load(Person.class,2);
session.evict(p); // does this make the entity detached?
```

I'm really confused as to which of the above approaches create a detached entity so any insights are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: *A detached entity is associated with a session*: no, it's not. *Will the entity p be considered detached*: yes. *is the following code a correct example of creating a detached entity?*: yes.

Comment: sorry that was a typo.. I know detached entity is not associated with a session.. so if I create a new object using Person p = new Person() and set its id to 2, will this create a detached entity since there is a DB record corresponding to the id 2? Or will the person obj be transient in this case?

Comment: which is not the JPA API. Kindly remove that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets be correct:

> When a managed entity object is serialized and then deserialized, the
>   deserialized entity object (but not the original serialized object) is
>   constructed as a detached entity object since is not associated with
>   any EntityManager.

And transient entity field:

> Transient entity fields are fields that do not participate in
>   persistence and their values are never stored in the database (similar
>   to transient fields in Java that do not participate in serialization).

Now you can conclude the answer of your questions.

Comment: Thanks .. that was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If we perform `session.evict(obj);` like following:

```
Person p = session.load(Person.class,2);
session.evict(p);
```

then POJO object is evicted or removed back from the persistent state to detached state.Soo this state of POJO object is detached state. After that GC(Garbage Collector) easily clean this object. So

```
session.evict(p); // does this make the entity detached? Yes it is in detached state.
```

Answer (score 0):

A entity is termed as detached when it is maintained by EntityManager and later it is detached say by calling evict() method.

Transient can be of two types.

1. When a field is annotated with @Transient then it will not participate in transient (can be correlated with @Transient of Serialization)
2. When you are preparing a new entity and yet to commit to database. When you call persist() - JPA's or save()-Hibernate's then it would change its state from transient to persistent.